# Post On user/page wall from Facebook application Offline

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I want to post on facebook page/user wall my new events offline what i mean is when i add a new event in the data base i post this events to user profile automatically is there is something like thread or something that check my new events and publish it to my applications user or page offline .I use Facebook c# sdk and mvc
thanks in advance 
any one want to edit my question or require more information are welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I can understand your question , you require an application should post too the wall even if you are offline.In short you require a facebook application with offline capabilities.

This can be done in a similar way as an application that does it online. Just save the uid of the user and the content , and when the app comes online , it will require the permission to post on the user's wall, and content can be posted.

Comment: by wnehn the app comes online you mean that it will be like a thread any new event will be published on the pages but what event should i put my code inside for now i am putting it in action where the user do publish it will publish

Comment: for any app to perform a task , such as post on the user wall it needs permissions from the user. when the app is offline, you can just save the contents to be posted and the uid of the user on whose profile it has to be posted, then ask the necessary permissions when it comes online and post the contents.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to be sure to request "offline_access" permission from the user.

```
var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer {  Permissions = "offline_access" };
```

Once the user adds your app, you'll need to save the auth token that is generated, which will be a "long-lived" token that can be used offline.

```
saveToDatabase(auth.Session.UserId,auth.Session.AccessToken)
```

In your event handler, you would then simply loop through all users, using the saved tokens for authorization, and make a post call.

```
foreach(var fbUser in SavedUsers) {
    fbClient.AccessToken = fbUser.SavedAccessToken;
    fbClient.Post(<desired post info>);
}
```

Comment: is that will be in the first action in my application and is going to post as an application on facebook fan page not application page because i try it and it post on the application page

Comment: Would you please send me more information about how to do it and about the CanvasAuthorizer can i put it inside any action as i work with mvc Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you'd like a designated user to post programmatically, then you can simply generate an "offline_access" token when you're logged in as that user [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET), and then save that to your database.

As for posting automatically, a System.Threading.Timer should do the trick. 

`var t = new Timer(YourPostingFunction,null,6000,6000);`